Attic insulation around electrical fittings
The attic insulation in my house is wearing thin. It’s old R25 installed in 1988. Also at least 20% of the space is not insulated. There are lots of spaces around light fittings, wiring etc that have no insulation.
I am laying R-30 unfaced across the rafters to create a baffle. What is the standard practice on insulating around or over light housings ?
See pics.




First of all, while the title says "electrical", any junction boxes without a light or other device consuming electricity should not have any insulation contact issues.
It depends on the light fitting. Many are marked as IC or Insulation Contact and are allowed to be in contact with insulation. For example, this Commercial Electric IC fixture from Home Depot:

says in the instructions:

NOTE: This fixture is an IC type fixture. It may come in direct contact
with thermal insulation. It can be completely covered by thermal
insulation, as shown below.

On the other hand, some such as this Lithonia from Home Depot are rated as non-IC:

Note that the marketing details include: Great for corridors, lobbies, conference rooms, and offices which implies common use for commercial buildings. Multi-story commercial buildings normally have non-insulated drop ceilings, where non-IC fixtures will work just fine.
This particular fixture includes the warning:

Warning: Risk of fire. For Non-IC rated luminaires, do not install insulation within 3 inches of fixture sides or wiring compartment, nor above fixture in such a manner as to entrap heat.

but it is possible that others may have difference insulation offset requirements. In particular, modern fixtures such as these with integral LED lights produce far less heat than older fixtures designed to use incandescent bulbs.

LEDs are also more sensitive to heat than incandescent bulbs.  Putting them under insulation may cause them to fail more often, even if safe from fire.

@mdfst13 Generally speaking, code is about "prevent fire" and installation instructions are about "make sure device works properly". An overheating LED is more likely to kill itself than an incandescent. But the incandescent is more likely to burn the house down. Bottom line: follow code and instructions, and the instructions (if properly done) will incorporate the code requirements.

Are the boxes on the cans considered to be junction boxes?

@Huesmann Yes, they are.

So it would be a good idea, if they're gonna be covered up by insulation, to mark them somehow?

Not necessary. The access is considered to be by way of pulling the fixture down from the ceiling. You make a hole, run the cables, attached the cables in the box and then secure the fixture/box to the ceiling.
